# how do i fully migrate my git central repo (--bare)

Tags: git, clone, repo

We have setup a central_repo for out team.
Everyone from our team will do a `git clone` from the central_repo and then push back into there.

Now, there is a need for us to move the central_repo to another location due to the fact that we need to save disk space for the current host.

Can I just do this?

```
git clone --mirror /existing/path/central_repo  /new/path/central_repo
rm -rf /existing/path/central_repo
ln -s /new/path/central_repo /existing/path/central_repo
```

I did a simple testing myself, and seems like most of the commands are working. However, i just want to make sure that i do not miss out anything and screw up the project and put myself into an irreversible situation if anything happens.

Thank in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to move your central_repo to some other location in the same filesystem. Is that correct ?

Comment: If you can make sure to freeze all git actions on your current central repo (e.g: tell colleagues to not run `git push` until you say so, shutdown your local `gitlab` instance, suspend your CI jobs ...), you can simply run `mv /existing/path/central_repo  /new/path/central_repo` (followed by your `ln -s ...` command if you need to)

Comment: @LeGEC yes you are absolutely right. Oh Wow. Moving the bare repo is so easy? I can just simply run `mv` and it will still work perfectly fine??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to move your repository within the same system.

Is that is the case, and if you are in a situation where you can freeze all git actions on your current central repo, e.g:

- tell colleagues to not run `git push` until you say so,
- shutdown your local `gitlab` instance,
- suspend your CI jobs ...

you can simply run :

```
mv /existing/path/central_repo  /new/path/central_repo
ln -s /new/path/central_repo /existing/path/central_repo
```

note that the git actions you want to prevent are *write* actions (pushing new commits, updating a branch or a tag). *read* actions (`git clone` or `git fetch`, `git ls-remote` ...) will not alter the content of your central repository.

---

The sequence of actions you proposed is ok, there still is the issue of "something was updated between `git clone --mirror` and `rm -rf existing_repo`" (note that, unless you have 10k developers who can push at any moment, this issue is actually pretty small in practice).

IMHO you would still need to arrange for a "service down" window (which will be pretty short) to run your migration.

Also to be on the safe side, run :

```
mv /existing/path/central_repo /existing/path/central_repo_old

#rather than a straight:
rm -rf /existing/path/central_repo
```

This would at least allow you to inspect the content of `central_repo_old` before deleting it.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. Oh Wow. Moving the bare repo is so easy? I can just simply run mv and it will still work perfectly fine??